# Infer a functions return type that is declared as `any` by the containing object type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type for an object of functions to only allow string members of a specific enum as keys:

```
enum ESharedActions {
  SET_LOADING = 'SET_LOADING',
  SET_LOGGED_IN = 'SET_LOGGED_IN',
}

type SharedActions = { [key in ESharedActions]: (...args: any) => any }
```

By applying that type to my object, I'm not able to infer the return type of that objects functions, because I had to type it as `any` in the `SharedActions` type.

```
const sharedActions: SharedActions = {
  [ESharedActions.SET_LOADING]: (loading: boolean) => ({
    type: ESharedActions.SET_LOADING,
    loading,
  }),
  [ESharedActions.SET_LOGGED_IN]: (loggedIn: boolean) => ({
    type: ESharedActions.SET_LOADING,
    loggedIn,
  }),
};

const foo = sharedActions[ESharedActions.SET_LOADING](true) // infers to `any`, should infer to { type: ESharedActions, loading: boolean }
```

Is it possible to ensure `sharedActions` structure by using a type/interface without overriding its functions return type so that TypeScript is able to infer it correctly?

**Edit:**
I feel I haven't made my intention perfectly clear. My focus here lies on preventing someone to use a random key inside `sharedActions` but still have the inferred payload (e.g. `type` and `loading`) inferred for `foo`. Is this idea maybe too overprotective for a shared codebase?

Comment: So you don't want to change the `SharedActions` definition (?

Comment: I changed it to `(...args: any) => { type: ESharedActions, [key: string]: any }` temporarily but that way only `type` is available in `foo`, the remaining payload (e.g. `loading`, `loggedIn`) is lost.

Comment: Which part are you trying to limit, ..args or the return type?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your ShareActions declaration when assigning to foo :

```
const sharedActions = {
  [ESharedActions.SET_LOADING]: (loading: boolean) => ({
    type: ESharedActions.SET_LOADING,
    loading,
  }),
  [ESharedActions.SET_LOGGED_IN]: (loggedIn: boolean) => ({
    type: ESharedActions.SET_LOADING,
    loggedIn,
  }),
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAogygCwIYCdgBMCCBjALgSwHsQBnKAbwFgAoKKOGAFQH0AZAeUwBEBJAOQDiUALxQA5AxYdu-AWIA0NOpLbsBAmF2b8R4lR3WbtfBTQC+NGtmIlcUEsjRY8RUrqq0oAbXiOMOAhsAOn1OXkEAXQAuKAAKABtCJHR8EABzGIAjQkJ44CQQAEoRAD44jzo6XABPAAdgGN9Ufxdg0JlBRU86ROTUtK66M0LB7yanANcSEKZVQy1+aLjEtLSMHhAsnLyC4uEy2IrKmvrGxGbnQNIZqTDZUZ7CVfWQUeGuswBuS2prUjsAGY5XQOC6TGw+c4TVrXdrhAQRWK4FBgYCFIA)

There are cases where you would prefer typing instead of infering. Here, if your intention is to consider sharedActions as a `SharedActions`(meaning having `(...args: any) => any` as value object), then do it like you did in your example.
If your intention is to manipulate the content of sharedActions, then infer types without declaring `SharedActions`

Then you, when you really need to use it as a type, cast it later :

```
const sharedActions = {
  [ESharedActions.SET_LOADING]: (loading: boolean) => ({
    type: ESharedActions.SET_LOADING,
    loading,
  }),
  [ESharedActions.SET_LOGGED_IN]: (loggedIn: boolean) => ({
    type: ESharedActions.SET_LOADING,
    loggedIn,
  }),
};

// use sharedAction
// doStuff(foo.loading)


// cast finally if your only goal is to expose the result as a SharedActions type/interface
// return sharedAction as SharedActions
```

Comment: I see - I just felt the need to "protect" `sharedActions`' structure by enforcing the enum key via the `SharedActions` type so nobody is able to use some random key. Maybe I'm overprotective here. Thanks!